# limit of supremum of Green's function, $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} (\sup_{z \in \partial B(x,\epsilon)} |G(x,z)|$) for $n \geq 3$

Tags: limits, partial-differential-equations, supremum-and-infimum, greens-function, fundamental-solution

How to determine $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} (\sup_{z \in \partial B(x,\epsilon)} |G(x,z)|$) for $n \geq 3$?

I know that $G(x,z) = \phi (z-x) - w^{x}(z)$.

And for $n \geq 3$ the fundamental solution is given by: $\hspace{2mm}$ $\phi(z-x) = \frac{1}{(n-2)w_{n}} \cdot \frac{1}{|z-x|^{n-2}} = \frac{1}{(n-2)w_{n}} \cdot \frac{1}{\epsilon^{n-2}}$

Now I also want to express the corrector function $w^{x}(z)$ in terms of $\epsilon$, but I don't know how. Or is the corrector function bounded on $\partial B(x,\epsilon)$?

In the lecture notes I can only find that: $w^{x}(z) = \phi(\frac{|x|}{r}z - \frac{r}{|x|}x)$ for $x \neq 0$, $x \neq z$ and $w^{x}(z) = \frac{1}{(n-2)w_{n}} \cdot \frac{1}{r^{n-2}}$ for $x = 0$ ($n \geq 3$). But here $z$ is in $\partial B_{r}(0)$. And I want that $z \in \partial B(x, \epsilon)$.

Comment: This question is due to the proof of Lemma 13 from https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220b/handouts/greensfcns.pdf .  At the end of page 13 $v(x)$ is approximated by $\frac{1}{\epsilon^{n-2}}$ and I don't understand how.

Answer (score 1):

The function $w^x(\cdot)$ is bounded on the domain you are working on $\bar{\Omega}$ (the bound will depend on $x$). This follows from the maximum principle: $w^x$ solves the PDE
$$
\begin{cases}
    \Delta w^x = 0 & \text{ on } \Omega\\
    w^x(z) = \phi(z - x) & z \in \partial \Omega,
\end{cases}
$$
and $\phi(\cdot - x)$ is an explicit smooth function.

In the case of $\Omega$ a ball (which appears to be where you formulated the question) you actually can obtain an explicit formula for $w^x$: $w^x(z) = - C|x|^{2-n}\phi(z - x^*)$ where $x^*$ is the inversion of the point $x$, and in particular lies outside $\Omega$; this function is smooth on $\bar{\Omega}$.

Comment: But if $\epsilon$ tends to zero, then $\phi(z-x)$ becomes unbounded, since $\phi$ has a singularity at zero. And since $w^{x}(z) = \phi(z-x)$ on the boundary, then why remains $w^{x}(z)$ bounded?

Comment: And according to the maximum principle for harmonic functions, $\phi(z-x) = \min_{z \in \partial B (x, \epsilon)} w^{x}(z) \leq w^{x}(z) \leq \max_{z \in \partial B (x, \epsilon)} w^{x}(z) = \phi(z-x)$. So then we have: $w^{x}(z) = \phi(z-x)$. And then the limit is just zero (not converging to zero), since $G(x,z) = \phi(z-x) - w^{x}(z)$

Comment: The boundary values of $w^x$ (indeed, the function $w^x$ in general) do not depend on $\epsilon$, just as $\phi(\cdot - x)$ does not depend on $\epsilon$. The only thing that depends on $\epsilon$ is the set over which you are taking the supremum of the Green's function. $\phi(\cdot - x)$ is always unbounded, but it is bounded on $\partial \Omega$. The maximum principle is applied to $\Omega$, to say that $\sup_{\Omega}|w^x| \leq \sup_{z \in \partial \Omega} |\phi(x - z)|\leq C$.

Comment: And in case $\Omega$ is a ball $\partial B(x, \epsilon)$, in my lecture there the function $w^{x}(z)$ is also defined as: $w^{x}(z) = \phi(\frac{|x|}{\epsilon} (z - x^{*})$. But $|x|$ is $\epsilon$ here, right? So then $w^{x}(z) = \phi(z - x^{*})$.

Comment: If $\Omega$ itself is the ball $B_\epsilon(x)$, then (as perhaps you argue in the previous comment) $G(x, z)$ is $0$ on $\partial B_{\epsilon}(x)$ by definition and the limit is trivially $0$. However, that did not seem to be what you were asking in the original question, and is certainly not what is going on in the notes you link: there $\Omega$ is some fixed domain, $G$ is the Green's function for $\Omega$, and $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ is a tiny ball inside $\Omega$.

Comment: Okay, so with $\sup_{\Omega} |w^{x}| \leq \sup_{z \in \partial \Omega} |\phi(x-z)| \leq C$ you can conclude that $w^{x}$ is bounded on $\Omega = B_{\epsilon}(x)$ by some constant C. That means that $\phi(x-z)$ is also bounded by C on $\partial \Omega$. But I conclude that $\phi(z-x) = \frac{1}{(n-2)w_{n}} \cdot \frac{1}{\epsilon^{n-2}}$ with $z \in \partial \Omega = \partial B_{\epsilon}(x)$. And as $\epsilon$ converges to zero, we get that $\phi(z-x)$ becomes unbounded. And we did conclude that $\sup_{z \in \partial \Omega} |\phi(x-z)| \leq C$, which is a contradiction?